# How to disinfect ice cream from coronavirus?

Tags: covid-19, virus, food-safety, coronavirus, disinfection

It is well known that some ways to remove coronavirus from food are:

- washing/cleaning it carefully;
- heating it (e.g. in oven, microwave or a saucepan), at least 70 degrees for at least 5 minutes;
- waiting for some hours/days for the virus to decompose by itself.

But none of these strategies apply to ice cream. In particular, the first two strategies are impossible because you cannot wash or cook ice cream. And the last one cannot be used because it would melt. Plus, if you wait keeping the ice cream in the freezer for hours/days, the virus may actually survive, because it survives very easily at very low temperatures (even for years).

So I was wondering, is there any other way (perhaps suggested by some experts, in that case please provide a link) for food disinfection which may work even on ice cream? Or the only way to stay safe is just avoiding eating it?

Comment: Ice cream prepared by a licensed dairy or manufacturer in a modern country should be free of pathogens. The only way it could become contaminated would be if someone opened the container after it left the production facility.

Comment: Many thanks for this useful info, but I mean_any_ ice cream in general, including handmade ice cream (like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/FRFwxdrjZrh0Oa5_MeAbUVQVbonxcBSlsfQOB8e2oN7xTMd5WdwqMBdJlFYorQToou17TW5-y10lL_cSoeD-mrVTlFX-vrCLsklZAdg8Fn5K_TfCp-xrlt96iYZW8zSa-lcKeSl_asUsFW6HZQEu) for example). It's very famous and traditional in my country, and it is in average much tastier and healthier (if we exclude coronavirus) than industrial ice cream. But since that ice cream is put in boxes by people, if those people are infected then the ice cream may become infected as well.

Comment: I really can't imagine any way you could disinfect ice cream.

Comment: @CareyGregory Possibly freeze drying (at which point if could possibly be decontaminated with some heating) or maybe irradiation https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bk-2004-0875.ch001 

Neither process would likely be available to the average person.

Comment: @RudyB And how would you reconstitute it? Just adding water and freezing it would produce a block of ice.

Comment: @CareyGregory Irradiation would not require reconstitution, as the physical properties would not be changed. For the freeze-dried process, I would not recommend reconstitution. Either way, as both methods are very expensive, not readily available, and concurring with the old adage "an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure" I would recommend that food products are processed in a manner to preclude the necessity of this additional processing. It is far easier, quicker, and cheaper.

Comment: Many thanks to both, at this point I agree with @RudyB about the fact that perhaps the only way is just to _prevent_ infection, even for handmade ice cream, by making sure that the ice cream is made in a way such that prevention is possible. I was curious in particular about the use of ozone, which is a gas, to disinfect at least the surface of the icecream, hoping that the inside is safe since maybe the inside of the icecream might be a "hostile" environment for the virus. But perhaps, this would not be effective enough, and the ozone may stick on the icecream surface and it may be toxic.